# realm object server not starting on Digital Ocean

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I've installed ROS fine on Digital Ocean just now. ROS version is 2.0.17

Then, when running the `ros start` on CLI it throws the following error:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:9080
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1351:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1392:12)
    at doListen (net.js:1501:7)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:141:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

How can I release port 9080 so ROS can use it ? (ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

figured it out.

```
sudo netstat -lpn |grep :9080    <-- whats currently using port 9080
```

output will be:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::9080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1291/node
```

take the number "1291" (or whatever PID your system is using)

run:

```
sudo kill 1291
```

then:

```
ros start
```

should see output similar to this:

```
info: Loaded feature token capabilities=[Sync], expires=Wed Apr 19 2017 14:15:29 GMT+0000 (UTC)
info: Realm Object Server version 2.0.17 is starting
info: [sync] Realm sync server started ([realm-core-4.0.3], [realm-sync-2.1.1])
info: [sync] Directory holding persistent state: /home/sogo/data/sync/user_data
info: [sync] Operating mode: master_with_no_slave
info: [sync] Log level: info
info: [sync] Download log compaction is enabled
info: [sync] Max download size: 131072 bytes
info: [sync] Listening on 127.0.0.1:43184 (sync protocol version 22)
info: [http] 127.0.0.1 - GET /realms/files/%2F__wildcardpermissions HTTP/1.1 200 55 - 32.257 ms
info: [http] 127.0.0.1 - GET /realms/files/%2F__password HTTP/1.1 200 44 - 24.644 ms
info: [http] 127.0.0.1 - GET /realms/files/%2F__perm HTTP/1.1 200 40 - 5.688 ms
info: Autocreated admin user: realm-admin
info: Realm Object Server has started and is listening on http://0.0.0.0:9080
info: [http] 127.0.0.1 - GET /realms/files/%2F__admin HTTP/1.1 200 41 - 18.051 ms
info: [http] 127.0.0.1 - GET /realms/files/%2F__admin HTTP/1.1 200 41 - 4.879 ms
```